# Erro no Pycharm ao ler planilha do excel

Tags: python

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando fazer a leitura de uma planilha do excel, mas sempre recebo esse erro, alguém pode me ajudar por favor?
[image: erro no pycharm]

O programa faz a primeira leitura da planilha, ou seja, importa e abre, quando tento fazer qualquer outro comando depois disso, não consigo, sempre tenho esse erro!

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite Rodrigues!

Creio que pelo tipo de erro (KeyError/Erro de Chave) a linha/coluna "Prod A" informada na planilha "Dados Tear 18" não existe com esse nome.

Tente olhar se não colocou com outro nome, como "ProdA", "Prod a", "Produto A", etc.

Espero que consiga resolver.

Abraço

Comment: Boa noite Felipe, obrigado pela dica. Vou verificar com cuidado. Se eu conseguir retorno para informar. Abraço!